# CALayer objects not touchable within UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, caanimation

I have a UIScrollView in which there are many CALayer objects as sub layer. I am able to capture the touches in all these layers if the userInteraction of the scrollView is disabled. But in this case, scroll is not possible. I now want to capture the touches and also enable scrolling of the scrollView. Any Ideas how this can be done?

Comment: CALayer doesn’t handle events. Show us some code how your touch handling works.

Comment: Yeah definitely post code because CALayer should not be able to handle any events - need UIView upwards (upwards as in higher level of abstraction) for that.